# How to get precision and recall for multiclass image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I built an image classification model and I want to get precision and recall but I don't know how to get it.
here is my code and error
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi96d.png) [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnzrB.png)

Comment: You should not post a picture of the code but rather include it in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it can be done like this:

model.compile(... , metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])

UPD Also you can try use this package https://pypi.org/project/keras-metrics/

```
import keras_metrics
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
          metrics=['accuracy', keras_metrics.precision(), keras_metrics.recall() ])
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Now I looked at your error. And I see that you have a problem with the model.  How are your class labels encoded?  one-hot encoded target or integer target?

Comment: I ask this because 'categorical_crossentropy' works on one-hot encoded target, while 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' works on integer target

Comment: It's an integer target. my target is like
tf.Tensor([2 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 1 2 1 2 4 0 2 4 3 2 2 3 2 3 2], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)

Comment: my batch size is 32

Comment: Its ok. Can you show your full code? What is the value of data_augmentation?

Comment: sure. This is my code in google colab [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_ZRaH3avmCd-4Q3_8sN4G3VL8JaPRtk_?usp=sharing)

Comment: Good. You can try use package keras_metrics https://pypi.org/project/keras-metrics/

Comment: import keras_metrics

Comment: model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False), metrics=['accuracy', keras_metrics.precision(), keras_metrics.recall() ])